# My SQL grab last active users within one week

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a query and I'm not sure how to limit the users by last login date.  i only want to return the users who have logged in in the last week. Here's my query:

```
"SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` WHERE `DateLastLogin` < '[1WEEK]'"
```

The DateLastLogin is a datetime field.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The query or how to get time for one week ago?

Comment: How to get time for one week ago.  I think the rest of the query is fine.

Comment: Well < should be > :) What type is DateLastLogin ? Where do you want to generate the time? In SQL, server side?

Comment: DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) will give time one week ago. This takes current date and subtracts one week. See my answer for on how to use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WHERE DateLastLogin > ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)
```

Comment: Why not use DATESUB?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` WHERE `DateLastLogin` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Or

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` WHERE `DateLastLogin` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` WHERE `DateLastLogin` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"
```

Probably the query you are looking for is

```
"SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` WHERE `DateLastLogin` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use

```
strtotime('-1 week');
```

and that will output the unix time from one week ago

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Count(* ) FROM Users WHERE CreatedDate > DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.